# Is it possible to create a custom Date slicer on Power BI?

Tags: date, powerbi, visualization, slicers, appsource

I'm looking for a date slicer (see below proof of concept)

[image]

The main features should be:

1. The selection is aggregated by month
2. The text on top of the slicer should have the month and year just like how its illustrated above.

Any guidance on creating custom visualisations is appreciated!

**Attempt 1:**
The closest I could get is to use Timeline slicer

[image]

And this is the output I managed to create - is there a way I can get the year as well on the slicer next to the month? (`Nov-19` and not just `Nov`)
[image]

Comment: There is a custom visual that does this already in the store, and some others as well. https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380786?tab=Overview

Comment: thanks @Jon I've updated the question with an attempt - any ideas on how to get the year too in addition to the three letter month name?

Answer (score 1):

This was the closest I got.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61cTK.png)

To get this, you'll need to head to Visualizations > Format > Labels > Display All.

[Data Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh7YT.png)

[Range Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cUls.png)

To get the header, Visualizations > Format > Range Header.

Comment: thank you for taking the time out to share this!